# JQuery validate one number in relation to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm struggling with creating a validation rule which validates one number in relation to another.

I have a setting in my software which represents the maximum difference between two numbers - for this example let's say it's set at `0.02`

Say number A is `1.50`. Number B can now not be bigger than `1.52` (`1.50 + 0.02`). If a user types in `1.53`, this input will not validate.

How can I go about doing this?

```
<input type="number" name="numberA" />
<input type="number" name="numberB" />
```

```js
numberA: {
  required: true
},
numberB: {
  required: true,
  range: ??
}
```

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: There's nothing in jQuery validate that will do this by default. You'll need to define your own custom rule to validate one field based on the value of another

Comment: You also forgot to mention that `numberB` cannot be less than `numberA` or `1.50` in your example.  This is a critical bit of information to properly solving to problem.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    numberA: "required",
    numberB: {
      equalTo: "#numberA"
    }
  }
});
```

if it's not working then please give the name of validation jquery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but numberB is not supposed to be EQUAL to numberA. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end!

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
  range: function() {
      return [parseFloat($("#numberA").val()), parseFloat($("#numberA").val()) + 0.02];
  }
```

Comment: In your OP, you forgot to mention that `numberB` cannot be less than `numberA` or 1.50 in your example. This is a critical bit of information to properly solving to problem using the `range` method.